Hierarchical models and conditional independence
Suppose that we have a hierarchical model given by (this is Example 4.4.5 of Berger and Casella(2002))
\begin{align*}
X\mid Y&\sim\text{binomial}(Y,p),\\
Y\mid\Lambda&\sim\text{Poisson}(\Lambda),\\
\Lambda&\sim\text{exponential}(\beta).
\end{align*}
Is it possible to show that $X$ is conditionally independent of $\Lambda$ given $Y$? Or is this an implicit assumption that is made in this hierarchical model?
Intuitively, $\Lambda$ affects $X$ only through $Y$ and if $Y$ is given, the value of $\Lambda$ should have no effect on the value of $X$. However, I am trying to come up with a rigorous argument. We would have to show that
$$
f(x,\lambda\mid y)
=f(x\mid y)f(\lambda\mid y)
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
f(x\mid\lambda,y)
=f(x\mid y).
$$
We know how $f(x\mid y)$ looks like and we can use Bayes' theorem to calculate $f(\lambda\mid y)=f(y\mid\lambda)f(\lambda)/f(y)$. We have that
$$
f(x,\lambda\mid y)
=\frac{f(x,\lambda, y)}{f(y)}
=\frac{f(x\mid\lambda, y)f(y\mid\lambda)f(\lambda)}{f(y)}
$$
but I am not sure how to proceed with $f(x\mid\lambda,y)$. How can we obtain an expression of $f(x\mid\lambda,y)$?

is conditionally independent of Λ given  -- this also follows from d-separation. Λ -> $Y$ -> $X$ is a causal chain, where when the middle node is observed, the chain becomes inactive, making the end nodes independent.

Given that $X|Y \sim Binomial(Y,p)$, the distribution of $X$ depends only on $Y$ and $p$. The conditional posterior distribution of $X$ given $Y$ is proportional to the binomial likelihood times the prior for $p$
The expression for $f(X|y,\lambda)$ is
$$f(X|y,\lambda)=f(X|y)=\binom{y}{x}p^x(1-p)^{y-x}.$$

This can be proven even without using the probability distributions themselves. $\Lambda$ --> $Y$ --> $X$ is a causal chain and $Y$ is observed. To prove $X \perp \Lambda | Y$, observe -
$$p(x,\lambda|y) = \frac{p(x,y,\lambda)}{p(y)} = \frac{p(\lambda)p(y|\lambda)p(x|y)}{p(y)} = \frac{p(y,\lambda)p(\lambda)p(x|y)}{p(\lambda)p(y)} = p(\lambda|y)p(x|y)$$
We assume this happens when $p(\lambda) \neq 0$
